# Vnstat error on installing

Tags: 16.04, vnstat

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When I'm trying to install `vnstat` by running:

```
sudo apt-get install vnstat
```

I get the following error:

```
Error “E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)”
```

Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Did you run `apt autoclean && apt autoremove && apt update && apt dist-upgrade` before `apt install vpnstat` ?

Comment: `error code (1)` is too generic to identify the possible issue - please [edit] your question with a more complete error message